# Conditional selection two data-frames R

Tags: r, dataframe, bigdata, conditional-statements

Assume that `A` and `B` are two `dataframes`, what would be the fastest way to:

find the instances where `A>0` `and` `B<0`? i.e. `A` is greater than zero conditional on `B` being less than zero.

The two `dataframes`have equal dimensions, are very large (`>70GB`) and the operation is done for `column1` in `A` vs `coulmn1` in `B` etc..

```
A=c(-31.621, -40.149, -21.519, -33.773, -34.023, -38.345, -39.238, 
    -30.221, -22.278, 27.055)

B=c(-29.321, -26.398, -25.663, -26.423, -23.721, -17.418, -15.979, 
    -21.927, -16.398, -21.084)
```

Comment: Extract the column as a vector and then do the comparison `i1 <- df1[["A"]] > 0 & df2[["B"]] < 0`

Comment: It's a little confusing that you say `A` and `B` are data frames, but in your example code they are vectors... but I think it will be hard to beat the speed of `A > 0 & B < 0`, or (if they are data frames) `A[["column1"]] > 0 & B[["column1]] < 0`. Might be a little faster if you use `data.table`s instead of `data.frame`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

**OPTION 1 - Joining and then processing conditions**

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

A <- c(-31.621, -40.149, -21.519, -33.773, -34.023, -38.345, -39.238, 
       -30.221, -22.278, 27.055) %>% 
  enframe(name = "ID")

B <- c(-29.321, -26.398, -25.663, -26.423, -23.721, -17.418, -15.979, 
       -21.927, -16.398, -21.084) %>% 
  enframe(name = "ID")

A %>% 
  left_join(., B, by = "ID", suffix = c("_A", "_B")) %>% 
  mutate(condition = case_when(value_A > 0 & value_B < 0 ~ T,
                               TRUE ~ F))

#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>       ID value_A value_B condition
#>    <int>   <dbl>   <dbl> <lgl>    
#>  1     1   -31.6   -29.3 FALSE    
#>  2     2   -40.1   -26.4 FALSE    
#>  3     3   -21.5   -25.7 FALSE    
#>  4     4   -33.8   -26.4 FALSE    
#>  5     5   -34.0   -23.7 FALSE    
#>  6     6   -38.3   -17.4 FALSE    
#>  7     7   -39.2   -16.0 FALSE    
#>  8     8   -30.2   -21.9 FALSE    
#>  9     9   -22.3   -16.4 FALSE    
#> 10    10    27.1   -21.1 TRUE
```

**OPTION 2 - Processing conditions and then joining**

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

A <- c(-31.621, -40.149, -21.519, -33.773, -34.023, -38.345, -39.238, 
       -30.221, -22.278, 27.055) %>% 
  enframe(name = "ID") %>% 
  filter(value > 0)

B <- c(-29.321, -26.398, -25.663, -26.423, -23.721, -17.418, -15.979, 
       -21.927, -16.398, -21.084) %>% 
  enframe(name = "ID") %>% 
  filter(value < 0)

A %>% 
  left_join(., B, by = "ID", suffix = c("_A", "_B"))

#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>      ID value_A value_B
#>   <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1    10    27.1   -21.1
```

**OPTION 3 - Processing conditions and finding index that matches condition**

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

A <- c(-31.621, -40.149, -21.519, -33.773, -34.023, -38.345, -39.238, 
       -30.221, -22.278, 27.055) %>% 
  enframe(name = "ID") %>% 
  filter(value > 0)

B <- c(-29.321, -26.398, -25.663, -26.423, -23.721, -17.418, -15.979, 
       -21.927, -16.398, -21.084) %>% 
  enframe(name = "ID") %>% 
  filter(value < 0)

intersect(A$ID, B$ID)
#> [1] 10
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It would be much more efficient to filter the A and B conditions first and then join with smaller data frames (assuming a join is needed at all).

Comment: Thank you! I just put two other options in my answer.

Comment: You're really running with this assumption that there's an ID column... speaking from experience I'd avoid doing **too** much work on an answer depending on such strong assumptions

Comment: I assumed there's an ID column or something like that because the question expressly states that A and B are **two data frames** - although they seem to be vectors.

Comment: Yes, but it also states they have they have "equal dimensions", which might mean the are to be operated on positionally without an id, which (if possible) would be quite a bit more efficient than any join.